# How to mimic <table border="2" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="40%"> in CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I have a simple html table element.

```
<table border="2" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="40%">
    <tr><td> aaa </td><td> bbb </td></tr>
    <tr><td> ccc </td><td> ddd </td></tr>
</table>
```

Now doing my first steps in CSS, I'm try trying **to define the latter table style as CSS** .

**I cannot achieve it - the border looks different whatever I do.
Please help.**

My HTML with CSS style :

```
<style type="text/css">
table.my_class
{
    width:40%;
}
table.my_class,table.my_class tr, table.my_class td
{
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style:groove;
    padding:15px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
</style>

<table class="my_class">
    <tr><td> aaa </td><td> bbb </td></tr>
    <tr><td> ccc </td><td> ddd </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If it is tabular data then use tables.

Comment: first close the "style" class, and you have repeated the "padding"

Comment: without normalize/reset css my solution is broken. I made other do not need reset. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/G8JvV/2/)

Comment: You should know that the display of a table without CSS varies by browser. Therefor, your first example will look slightly different depending on the user. It appears a much darker colour in chrome than in firefox, for example. You'd be best off choosing a style of your liking and just using that.

Comment: Yes, I see. And the real "killer" is the html renderer of MS Word(used by Outlook 2007).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML

```
<table border="2" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="40%">
    <tr><td> aaa </td><td> bbb </td></tr>
    <tr><td> ccc </td><td> ddd </td></tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table class="mytable">
    <tr><td> aaa </td><td> bbb </td></tr>
    <tr><td> ccc </td><td> ddd </td></tr>
</table>​
```

---

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/G8JvV/2/) is the solution without reset.css
CSS

```
table.mytable {
 width: 40%;
 border: 2px solid #444;  
 border-spacing: 0;    
}

table.mytable tr {border-bottom: 1px solid #444}

table.mytable td{
  border-right: 1px solid #444;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 5px;
}

table.mytable tr td:last-child{ border-right: 0 }
table.mytable tr:last-child td{ border-bottom: 0 }
```

---

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/G8JvV) is the solution with reset.css
CSS

```
table.mytable {
 width: 40%;
 border: 2px solid #000;    
}

table.mytable td{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
​
```

Comment: In both fiddles the two tables look different (Chrome)

Comment: Not bad... Still different. Does it mean I cannot "translate" html attributes into CSS and the only way is to try different styles manually?

Comment: If your jsFiddle demos expire, your answer becomes useless. Please post the code directly in your answer, too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can translate the attributes exactly the way you like... Because at the time, the standards were not applied to that degree and usually things look different in different browsers. Your best shot is try to tune it something close.

```
    <!doctype HTML>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta content="">
        <style>
        .tbl
        {
            width:40%;
            border: solid 2px black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        .tbl td
        {
            padding: 5px;
            border: solid 2px black;
        }

        </style>
      </head>
      <body>

        <table border="2" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="40%">
        <tr><td> aaa </td><td> bbb </td></tr>
        <tr><td> ccc </td><td> ddd </td></tr>
        </table>
        <br/><br/>
        <table class="tbl">
        <tr><td> aaa </td><td> bbb </td></tr>
        <tr><td> ccc </td><td> ddd </td></tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using an unstyled table with the `border` attribute, the borders look different in different browsers. Some browsers draw solid borders, some draw outset borders for the table and inset borders for the cells, etc. There is no way achieve this variation in CSS. And hardly any need for it. Just select the preferred rendering, after having considered the various tools that CSS has to offer and that considerably exceed the capabilities presentational HTML attributes (except in creating some browser dependencies).