# What is the equivalent of border="1" in CSS for table?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I would like to use the CSS equivalent of `border="1"` through an equivalent stylesheet definition.

The `border-width` and `border-style` applies for the table but the cell borders which are given by `border="1"` are missing out.

Comment: Already answered a similar question in this topic -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189005/how-to-mimic-table-border-2-cellpadding-5-cellspacing-0-width-40-in-c/11189342#11189342

Answer (score 9):

So this should be an easy answer but when you use CSS table and td its doesn't quite match border="1" 100% (But its very close)

[image]

My way uses this:

```
table { 
        border: 1px outset grey;
        padding: 1px 
  }

td { 
            border: thin inset grey;
            margin: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Apply it to the `td` elements instead of `table` element.

Comment: Made this for my own answer, but you gave the answer before me, so: http://jsfiddle.net/mB594/

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
td { border: solid 1px #PlaceColorHere }
```

Comment: Thank you. But I can not directly override TD because there are other definitions of it in the page which will be in jeopardy. KayKay's suggestion worked.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    table {
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: groove;
    }
    td {
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: inset;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some tables which want internal borders and some which don't, to differentiate, create a class "border1". The html changes to :

```
<table class="border1">
```

and add css :

```
.border1, .border1 th, .border1 td
{
    border: 1px solid black
}
```

which creates a border for the table as well as the cells inside.